# ReactJs - How to force hover to test styles on hover of material-ui (v5 +) components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hover, react-testing-library, ts-jest

**How to force hover to test styles on hover of material-ui (v5 +) components?** for example on [Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/)

Notes:

- This componenent works as expected.
- I'm sure that it's not a duplicate.
- In Debug, the `background-color` value keep equals to my initial value *(variable `defaultBackgroundColor`)*
- *After this I want test it using my theme created with `createTheme`.*

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('Testing hover on Button from @mui ', () => {
    it('Hover', async () => {
        const defaultBackgroundColor: string = '#b3c';
        const hoverBackgroundColor: string = '#ccc !important';
        render(
            <Button
                data-testid="button"
                style={{ backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor }}
                sx={{
                    '&:hover ': {
                        backgroundColor: hoverBackgroundColor
                    }
                }}
            >
                MyButtonWithHover
            </Button>
        );
        const buttonEl: HTMLButtonElement = screen.getByTestId('button');

        /* This initial expect it's ok */
        expect(buttonEl).toHaveStyle(`
            background-color: ${defaultBackgroundColor};
        `);
        
        // Now I need apply hover on buttonEl before that the below expect: the background-color is esquals to hoverBackgroundColor

        expect(buttonEl).toHaveStyle(`
            background-color: ${hoverBackgroundColor};
        `);

    });
});
```

My attempts:

```
const mouseEnter = fireEvent.mouseEnter(buttondEl);
```

```
const mouseOver = fireEvent.mouseOver(buttondEl);
```

```
const mouseUp = fireEvent.mouseUp(buttonEl);
```

```
        const buttonEl = await waitFor(async () => {
            await userEvent.hover(buttonEl, { delay: 0 });
            return screen.getByTestId('button');
        });
```

My setup: [SharebookBR/sharebook-frontend-next](https://github.com/SharebookBR/sharebook-frontend-next)